# Acts 1:12 ~ Shabbat days walk

Tags: acts

- The passages that come after Jesus ascended into heaven in acts 1 talks about the disciples coming down from the mount of olives
- Acts says that the mount of olives is a Shabbat days walk === .62 Miles / 1 Km.
- Question #1: So did Jesus ascend into heaven from the mount of olives?
- Question #2: If you see the map below and measure the distance as a straight line(assuming there were no sophisticated roads back then, **See Yellow Line**) it would be at least 3 km *if we measure to the city pin on Google, which they didn't use*. That location would be discrepancy. What specific place in Jerusalem was probably being used to measure this distance from?

> **Acts 1:9** After he said this, he was taken up before their very eyes, and a cloud hid him from their sight. **10** They were looking intently up into the sky as he was going when suddenly two men dressed in white stood beside them. **11** “Men of Galilee,” they said, “why do you stand here looking into the sky? This same Jesus, who has been taken from you into heaven, will come back in the same way you have seen him go into heaven.”

> **Acts 1:12** Then the apostles returned to Jerusalem from the hill called the **Mount of Olives**, a **Sabbath day’s walk**[c] from the city.

[image]

Comment: As Acts 1:12 explicitly says, a [Sabbath's walk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Techum_shabbat) is measured from the city limits.

Comment: @Lucian, Actually the Shabbat day's walk is around .62 miles / 1 km from where you are or within the city limits. This was so to enable rest and people dont move too much. That said the old city of Jerusalem is just about 1 square km so does not really matter. https://www.travelingisrael.com/old-city-jerusalem/

Comment: And in those *many documents from the Jewish writings*, have you ever come across the basic fact that the distance in question is to be measured from the circle or rectangle comprising the city ? Have you even bothered clicking the link, during all this time ?

Comment: @Lucian, I have read your link. Please see this https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16170/jewish/Chapter-2.htm

Comment: I have; how is it connected to this question ?

Comment: In your graphic and your measurements, you're defining "Jerusalem" as a pin on a Google Map, while the text is talking about the city limit. It's not even the same place and it's not even what the text was talking about. So, you're "Question #2" is a straw man—*why does it say [this thing is actually doesn't say]?* I'm editing this to clean that up.

Comment: The map is also wrong. You can see the temple mount *right next to the ridge*. The closest distance between the temple and the mount is like 200 meters. For some reason, the google pin is far away from the temple, far outside the city limits of Jerusalem in Herod's day. And the pin for Mount of Olives is on the West side of the mount. The maps is really misleading. I included a map in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Acts 1:12

> Then the apostles returned to **Jerusalem** from the hill called the **Mount of Olives**, a Sabbath day's walk from the city.

Your map show today's Jerusalem. Acts 1 is talking about Jerusalem two thousand years ago. Also, Jerusalem was a big city. Acts 1 does not specify precisely where in Jerusalem was the spot that the apostles returned to.

So did Jesus ascend into heaven from the mount of olives?

Luke 24:

> 50When Jesus had led them out as far as **Bethany**, He lifted up His hands and blessed them. 51While He was blessing them, He left them and was **carried up** into heaven. 52And they worshiped Him and returned to Jerusalem with great joy

Bethany was a village on the Mount of Olives.

Acts 1:

> 9 After he [Jesus] said this, he was taken up before their very eyes, and a cloud hid him from their sight.
>
> 10 They were looking intently **up into the sky** as he was going, when suddenly two men dressed in white stood beside them. 11“Men of Galilee,” they said, “why do you stand here looking into the sky? This same Jesus, who has been taken from you into heaven, will come back in the same way you have seen him go into heaven.”
>
> 12Then the apostles returned to Jerusalem from the hill called the **Mount of Olives**, a Sabbath day’s walk from the city.

The traditional site of the Ascension is the Mount of Olives, on which the village of Bethany sits.

Comment: Tony, Archeologists have found David's Palace and the Old City. They have proof that the place has items that date 3000 years old. The disciples would have met somewhere in the city and and it does not really matter as the old city of Jerusalem is just about 1 square km https://www.travelingisrael.com/old-city-jerusalem/

Comment: Check this link has a lot of information pertinent to Jesus teaching across towns and villages https://www.bible-history.com/map_jesus/MAPJESUSNew_Testament_Cities_Distances.htm

Answer (score 0):

It may have been on Sabbath for the mere fact that the text mentions it. If so, it would be clarifying that the Sabbath law was not broken, even after the ascension. That is relevant to other passages that may discuss whether the law still applies. Either way, it was not broken here.

This is based on hermeneutics of "context", that mentioning a thing means there is an implied need. However, it is inductive, not deductive, so it cannot be certain. It also could have been a mere unit of measurement. But, we can't escape from the fact that the author may have found a good reason to bring it up, specifically that the law was not broken, thus it could have likely been on a Sabbath.

Comment: Hi, Nancy! Answers here need a little more meat. I added that for you. Good thoughts, though.

Answer (score 0):

"A sabbath day's walk" is used as a unit of distance. It has nothing to do with trying to observe the sabbath.

Jesus ascended 40 days after rising from the dead on a Sunday. That would make this a *Thursday*. This is why Christians celebrate [Ascension Thursday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feast_of_the_Ascension). Nothing that happened on that day has anything to do with Sabbath observance.

What matters is the unit of distance provided to give people a proper sense of orientation. Just like I can say that something weighed "A Temple Shekel" and this does not mean I was performing sacrifices in the temple, or serving in the Temple, or really doing anything at all in the temple. It is a unit of measurement.

The mount of olives is a ridge to the East of Jerusalem. By specifying the distance they walked, we have some information about where the disciples were on that ridge. Thus the mention of the distance traveled is not about observing the Sabbath, but providing more specificity.

Acts 1:12 (KJV 1900)

> Then returned they unto Jerusalem from the mount called **Olivet, which
> is from Jerusalem a sabbath day’s journey.**

Assuming they were walking from the Church of Nations to the Water Gate - the nearest public gate -- that distance would be about 2.5 1/4 miles or 0.625 miles, or about a Sabbath day's walk. This does not mean that they had to be at the church of the nations location, but I think it makes this a good candidate site for the ascension.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://biblehub.com/interlinear/acts/1-12.htm

The text says "a Sabbath day’s holding journey".  I wonder if the "a Sabbath day’s journey" used as a unit of measurement is a mistranslation. For me "a Sabbath day’s holding journey" could really mean "journey" + "happened" + "on the sabbath" in reverse order. Which means Jesus' ascension happend on a sabbath.

Thus, "a Sabbath day’s journey" translation as a unit of measurement is used to hide the fact. Why? Maybe the archenemy wanted to hide this in plain sight. Remember as the disciples were gazing up in the sky the two men stood my them in white apparel AKJV V10 and said in V11 ... "this same Jesus, which is taken up from you into heaven, shall so come in like manner as you have seen him go into heaven."

And if "manner" includes the manner of time as in the 4 WH elements of a good news, Jesus will come on a sabbath day to give us all rest from the toils and hardship of this world.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Acts 1:12 is one of my favourite bible verses.
Seemingly innocuous but perhaps one of the most elegantly simple "hidden in plain sight" expositions of scripture.

#### Acts 1:11-12 points to the momentous return, by the seemingly innocuous inclusion of the location.

> "This same Jesus, who has been taken from you into heaven, **will come back in the same way** you have seen him go into heaven.”
>
> ***Then the apostles returned to Jerusalem from the hill called the Mount of Olives, a Sabbath day’s walk from the city.***
>
> Acts 1:11-12 NIV

The reference to the reversal of this event, i.e. the return of the king,  found more descriptively in Revelation :

> ... ***the kings of the whole world, to gather them for the battle on the great day of God Almighty***.
>
> “Look, **I come like a thief!**”
>
> Then they gathered the kings together to the place that in Hebrew is called Armageddon.
>
> “**It is done!**” Then there came ... ***a severe earthquake***. ***No earthquake like it has ever occurred since mankind has been on earth, so tremendous was the quake***.
>
> Revelation 16:14,15,16,17-18 NIV

A gathering to battle, during which time Jesus returns, then the battle, at which point Jesus manifests himself and there is a great earthquake.

These events portrayed in Zechariah :

> ***I will gather all the nations to Jerusalem to fight against it*** ...
>
> Then the Lord will go out and fight against those nations, as he fights on a day of battle.
>
> **On that day his feet will stand on the Mount of Olives**, **east of Jerusalem**, and the Mount of Olives will be split in two from east to west, forming ***a great valley*** ...
>
> **Then the Lord my God will come, and all the holy ones with him**.
>
> On that day there will be neither sunlight nor cold, frosty darkness. It will be a unique day—a day known only to the Lord—with no distinction between day and night. When evening comes, there will be light.
>
> On that day *living water will flow out from Jerusalem* ...
>
> It will be inhabited; never again will it be destroyed. Jerusalem will be secure.
>
> Zechariah 14:2,3,4,5,6-7,8,11 NIV

The great earthquake tearing the land in two, as the veil of the temple was torn in two, and the fountains of the deep once again bringing forth life for the few :

> Then the angel showed me ***the river of the water of life*** ... flowing ... down the middle of the great street of the city.
>
> Revelation 22:1-2 NIV

An incredible amount of parallels between this portion of Zechariah and the culmination of Revelation.

> This same Jesus, who has been taken from you into heaven, **will come back in the same way** you have seen him go into heaven.”
>
> ***Then the apostles returned to Jerusalem from the hill called the Mount of Olives, a Sabbath day’s walk from the city.***
>
> Acts 1:11-12 NIV

> On that day **his feet will stand on the Mount of Olives, east of Jerusalem** ...
>
> Zechariah 14:4 NIV

These three passages connected, Acts 1:11-12 skipping over the detail in a terse, matter of fact account, of the departure but pregnant through the simple description of the location, with the momentous return.

#### Acts 1:12 a shorthand to the return of the king and the millenial rule.

But wait, there's more!

It's not happenstance that the phrase a "sabbath's days walk from the city" is included, when any number of other descriptions of the distance could suffice, or simply none at all.
Anyone at any time can determine the geographical relation between these two locations, and further, the time it takes to walk on the sabbath, is the same as any other, time for bowing and scraping aside.

So why?
The key is not in the reference to the space between the two but in the method of describing that space.
On the surface, an indicator of time to walk, but a specific measure of time.

The return of christ to Jerusalem, when his feet stand again on the mountain of Olives, followed by :

> They came to life and reigned with Christ **a thousand years**. This is the first resurrection.
>
> Revelation 20:4,5 NIV

Four thousand years from Adam to Jesus and two thousand years from his departure to his return.
These two thousand years between the resurrection of the king and the following of his people at the "first resurrection" being typed here :

> ***After three days*** the officers went throughout the camp, giving orders to the people: “When you see the ark of the covenant of the Lord your God, and the Levitical priests carrying it, you are to move out from your positions and ***follow it***. Then you will know which way to go, since you have never been this way before. But **keep a distance of about two thousand cubits between you and the ark**; do not go near it.”
>
> Joshua 3:2-4 NIV

> But Christ has indeed been ***raised from the dead***, the firstfruits of those who have fallen asleep.
>
> But **each in turn**: Christ, the firstfruits; then, when he comes, those who belong to him.
>
> 1 Corinthians 15:20,23 NIV

A similar idea in that the measurement itself is of no consequence, the "two thousand" being the pertinent information, here representing years, elsewhere the "sabbath's walk" representing the millenial rest.

All this of course, typed by the six days of creation.

> “Where is this ‘coming’ he promised? Ever since our ancestors died, everything goes on as it has ***since the beginning of creation***.”
>
> ***With the Lord a day is like a thousand years, and a thousand years are like a day***.
>
> But the day of the Lord will **come like a thief**.
>
> 2 Peter 3:4,8,10 NIV

That coming being at the beginning of the seventh thousandth year, corresponding to the seventh day of creation, the sabbath.
That thousand year sabbath of rest, being the space between Jesus mountain of Olives return, and the **new Jerusalem** which appears *at the culmination of that seventh thousand year sabbath* :

> I saw the Holy City, **the new Jerusalem**, coming down out of heaven from God ...
>
> Revelation 21:2 NIV

The return, *then the sabbath journey*, then the **new** Jerusalem.

And of course the mountain of Olives being to the east, from where the sun rises, and so on and so forth.

#### Armageddon not a greek word.

Setting aside the abundance of allusions contained in the two verse description of the location of the departure of Jesus, perhaps one of the obvious takeaways is the failure of expositors to recognise the significance of :

> Then they gathered the kings together to the place that **in Hebrew** is called **Armageddon**.
>
> Revelation 16:16 NIV

Absolutely not Megiddo.

- Megiddo is understood equally in greek and hebrew. Everything in the scripture is by design. As with Abaddon and Apollyon, describing chronologically sequential events, first in the levant and then on the beast. Deliberate and not to be ignored.
- The great day of god almighty, where the nations are gathered to battle against Jerusalem ... takes place at Jerusalem. This is expressed clearly many times throughout scripture.

This battle and return are not only related literally (at Jerusalem) but ***also in metaphor***.

A prophecy which is variously described in the *hebrew* scriptures employing the figure of sheaves or **gathered wheat** (עָמַר aw-mar') in a **valley** (גַּיְא gah'-ee) for threshing or **judgement** (דִּין deen) - or in greek ΑΡΜΑΓΕΔΩΝ - Armageddon.

**עָמַר** - (aw-mar') - gathered wheat
**גַּיְא** - (gah'-ee) - in a valley
**דִּין** - (deen) - for judgement

> 'Then the iron, the clay, the bronze, the silver and the gold were all broken to pieces and became like **chaff on a threshing floor** in the summer. The wind swept them away without leaving a trace. But the rock that struck the statue became *a huge mountain and filled the whole earth*.'
>
> Daniel 2:35 NIV

This corresponding to the “It is done!” and the subsequent city :

> 'And he carried me away in the Spirit to *a mountain great and high*, and showed me the Holy City, Jerusalem, coming down out of heaven from God.'
>
> '... the Lord God Almighty and the Lamb *are its temple*.'
>
> '*The glory and honor of the nations will be brought into it*.'
>
> Revelation 21:10, 22, 26 NIV

Micah being eloquent to this *mountain* and *temple* and *worship* :

> 'In the last days
> *the mountain of the Lord’s temple* will be established
> as *the highest of the mountains*;
> it will be exalted above the hills,
> and *peoples will stream to it*.'
>
> '*Many nations* will come and say ...'
>
> “Come, let us go up to *the mountain of the Lord*,
> *to the temple* of the God of Jacob.
> He will teach us his ways,
> so that we may walk in his paths.”
> The law will go out from Zion,
> the word of the Lord from Jerusalem.'
>
> Micah 4:1-2 NIV

But also eloquent as to the **preceding events** :

> 'But now **many nations
>
> are gathered against you**.
> They say, “Let her be defiled,
> let our eyes gloat over Zion!”'
>
> 'But they do not know
> the thoughts of the Lord;
> *they do not understand his plan*,
> that he has **gathered them like sheaves to the threshing floor**.'
>
> “**Rise and thresh**, Daughter Zion,
> for I will give you horns of iron;
> I will give you hooves of bronze,
> and you will **break to pieces many nations**.”
>
> Micah 4:11-13 NIV

Joel is also eloquent as to these events :

> “In those days and at that time,
> when I restore the fortunes of Judah and Jerusalem,
> I will **gather all nations**
> and bring them down to **the Valley** of *Jehoshaphat*."
>
> Joel 3:1-2 NIV

*Jehoshaphat* being **the Lord judges**.

> “Let the nations be roused;
> let them advance into **the Valley** of *Jehoshaphat*,
> for there I will sit
> to **judge all the nations** on every side."
>
> "**Swing the sickle,
>
> for the harvest is ripe**."
>
> 'Multitudes, multitudes
> in **the valley of decision**!
> For the day of the Lord is near
> in **the valley of decision**.'
>
> Joel 3:12-14 NIV

Etcetera.

Wheat gathered into a valley for threshing.

**עָמַר** - (aw-mar') - gathered wheat
**גַּיְא** - (gah'-ee) - in a valley
**דִּין** - (deen) - for judgement

ΑΡΜΑΓΕΔΩΝ - Armageddon - is to be understood in **hebrew**. It is patently nothing to do with Megiddo, a name that is equally understood in greek.

And of course, Megiddo is neither a valley **nor** a mountain and has absolutely nothing to do with the return of christ to **Jerusalem**.

> "This same Jesus, who has been taken from you into heaven, ***will come back in the same way you have seen him go*** into heaven.”
>
> Then the apostles returned to **Jerusalem** from the hill called **the Mount of Olives**, a Sabbath day’s walk from the city.
>
> Acts 1:11-12 NIV

Acts 1:12 is deliberately blunt.

> **On that day his feet will stand on the Mount of Olives, east of Jerusalem**, and the Mount of Olives will be split in two from east to west, **forming a great valley** ...'
>
> Zechariah 14:4 NIV

Etcetera.